# classCastException on getExtra() from a Parcelable Object in a Service

Tags: android, service, location, classcastexception, parcelable

I'm trying to implement a Service and I have a classCastException in my Service.
Since Location isn't Parcelable I wrap it in a ParcelableArrayList.

```
public class GPSService extends Service {
    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        ArrayList<Location> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<Location>(1);
        locationArrayList.add(location);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelableArrayList("location", locationArrayList);
        // try with an arrayList instead of just getExtra doesn't change anything :(
        ArrayList<GPSResultReceiver> resultReceiverArrayList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("receiver");
        // this is a resultReceiver and not a GPSResultReceiver
        // where did the upcast happen?
        GPSResultReceiver receiver = resultReceiverArrayList.get(0);
        Log.d("ResultClass", receiver.getClass().toString());
        receiver.onReceiveResult(1111, b);
    }
```

My Activity looks as following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements GPSResultReceiver.Receiver {
    void startService() {
        resultReceiver = new GPSResultReceiver(new Handler());
        resultReceiver.setReceiver(this);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, null, this, GPSService.class);
        // intent.putExtra("receiver", resultReceiver);
        ArrayList<GPSResultReceiver> resultReceiverArrayList = new ArrayList<GPSResultReceiver>(1);
        resultReceiverArrayList.add(resultReceiver);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("receiver", resultReceiverArrayList);
        serviceRunning = true;
        startService(intent);
    }
```

My GPSResultReceiver:

```
public class GPSResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    private Receiver resultReceiver;
    public GPSResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }
    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        resultReceiver = receiver;
    }
    public interface Receiver {
        public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        if (resultReceiver != null) {
            resultReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }
    }
}
```

So why does this cast occur here and how can I work around it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like Location IS Parcelable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#writeToParcel%28android.os.Parcel,%20int%29 states"implements Parcelable", ResultReceiver is also Parcelable.

Comment: Where exactly do you have ClassCastException?

Comment: GPSResultReceiver receiver = resultReceiverArrayList.get(0); You can cast it to Object and you'll see the class is ResultReceiver and not GPSResultReceiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it works as expected, because [CREATOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html#CREATOR%20CREATOR) of ResultReceiver creates ResultReceiver, but not it's child classes.
The point here is following: actually, You don't need GPSResultReceiver in the service. Just ResultReceiver is quite enough to send results back, but You should call [public void send (int resultCode, Bundle resultData)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html#send%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29), but not `onReceiveResult`.
So, it would look like
Service:

```
public class GPSService extends Service {

    Intent intent = null;
    ResultReceiver receiver = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(final Intent inIntent, final int startId) {

        super.onStart(inIntent, startId);

        this.intent = inIntent;
        setLocation(null);
    }

    void setLocation(final Location location) {
        final ArrayList<Location> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<Location>(1);
        locationArrayList.add(location);
        final Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putParcelableArrayList("location", locationArrayList);

        try {
            this.receiver = this.intent.getParcelableExtra("com.example.testservice.TestResultReceiver");
        } catch (final ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e("GPSService", "Failed to cast to  GPSResultReceiver", e);
        }

        try {
            this.receiver = GPSResultReceiver.class.cast(this.intent.getParcelableExtra("com.example.testservice.TestResultReceiver"));
        } catch (final ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e("GPSService", "Failed to cast to  GPSResultReceiver 2", e);
        }

        Log.d("ResultClass", this.receiver.getClass().toString());
        this.receiver.send(1111, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, should have seen that with the CREATOR in the docs. I can not up vote as I don't have enough reputation yet.